# Using FFMPEG to Live Stream Files via HLS Without Re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

everyone! I sure hope someone can help me. FFMPEG has to be able to do what I want to do.

Here's what I want to do: I want to live stream (i.e., broadcast) files from my hard disk via HLS. The files are already encoded exactly as I want them, so there is no need to re-encode. All I want to do is use FFMPEG to copy the files from MP4 to an HLS stream output.

If you just say copy sample.mp4 to HLS, FFMPEG works fine: It very quickly spits out the entire MP4 file into multiple .ts files with an accurate corresponding M3U8 file.

But here's the problem: This is not broadcast. This is on demand. The difference being that when a viewer joins a live broadcast, the viewer should join the show already in progress. For example, if I'm airing an hour long show called "Trucker Diaries" that starts at, say, 7PM, if my viewer tunes in at, say, 7:15PM, he should not start seeing the video from the start, but rather, fifteen minutes already in.

So FFMPEG should generate the M3U8 file on the fly in "live" mode. Every X number of seconds, FFMPEG should update the M3U8 file by adding the next segment to the bottom of the playlist and removing the old one from the top.

Here's the thing: If I tell FFMPEG to re-encode, it works fine. Since it takes FFMPEG a few seconds to render each segment, it updates the M3U8 file as each segment is done rendering.

But because I am copying and not re-encoding, the process goes too quickly! FFMPEG does update the M3U8 file as described, but it's done updating it in a fraction of a second, not incrementally every few seconds the way it should. So I wind up with an M3U8 playlist that just contains the very last few segments of the show. There has to be a way to tell FFMPEG, "Hey, update the playlist file once per however long each segment is."

I hope this makes sense. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Assuming you're already using ffmpeg hls in live mode, you should be reading the source at realtime speed, by adding `-re` before `-i`.